# Datetime doesnt display week number

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a web app that extracts information on dates. What i want is to extract the week number for the whole year.

```
DateTime nicole = new DateTime();

for (int i = 1; i <= 366; i++)
 {
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci =     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;


  Int32 weekNo = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                    new DateTime(nicole.Year,nicole.Month,nicole.Day),
                    ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                    ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
                );
  response.write(ci);

 }
```

The result of this is

```
 en-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-USen-
```

Please help!

Comment: Don't you want to print `weekNo`? You are obviously printing the current culture...

Comment: I see a couple of issues with your code, 1. in the weekNo you always get the weeknumber for the same date `    new DateTime(nicole.Year,nicole.Month,nicole.Day),`. 2. You are doing a `response.write(ci);`. Should it not be `response.write(weekNo);`

Comment: Indeed. You're printing out the CultureInfo, not the date. Also you are creating the same DateTime object 365 times.
What exactly are you trying to do? Print out the week number of every day in a year?

Comment: Seriously, read your code before asking... you're printing `ci` instead of `weekNo`.

Comment: why did you say that I get the week number for the same date?

Comment: Because you inizialize the date once `DateTime nicole = new DateTime();` and then never change it. And in the `for` loop you keep creating a new `DateTime` but always with the same year-month-day as your original nicole which doesn't change.

Comment: @user1954418 Could you give us a new description of what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want to display the week numbers for the whole year - but that will always give you a list (or array) containing 1 through 52. The list may start at a different point but will always contain 1-52.

Comment: its okay now guys.its working. but funny thing though, the total weeks i get for the whole year is 53, should it be 52?

Comment: yes, i want to display the week numbers for the whole year.and using my code above.i was able to accomplish that.as far as i know, there's nothing wrong on my output.

Comment: 52 * 7 = 364.  There's the start of a 53rd week in every year.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing `ci` - the CultureInfo.
Try writing `weekNo` instead.  That would be the int representing the week.  Though it will write 367 numbers on one line.  You might want your output line to read

```
response.write(ci.ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Edit - It's likely that you want to use your for loop, perhaps as follows?

```
Int32 weekNo = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                new DateTime(nicole.Year,nicole.Month,i),
                ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
            );
response.write(ci);
```

Further edit.  As comments said, advancing `i` here won't help, since it's in the day-of-month position.  Instead, the code should be as:

```
Int32 weekNo = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                new DateTime(nicole.Year,1,1).AddDays(i),
                ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
            );
response.write(ci);
```

Comment: +1. Passing 1-365 value as "day of the month" is wrong and cause exception - use `AddDays` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  Fixed it as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

response.write(weekNo);

as the last statement of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted

```
response.write(weekNo); // not write(ci)
```

Don't forget to add some sort of separators.

Side note: depending on the framework you are using (MVC? plain ASP.Net, something else) there could be better way to return structured data. I.e. [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in MVC may be more suitable for list of values than string with numbers without separators.

Side note 2: to get correct "day of the year" use different constructor and [AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) :

```
  new DateTime(nicole.Year,1,1).AddDays(i-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really the answer to your question, but maybe it's what you're trying to do:

```
var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
var ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
var nicole = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
while (nicole.Year == year)
{
    response.write(ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(nicole, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek));
    nicole = nicole.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: thank you for all of your answers :) stupid mistake of mine. im sorry :))